Proof that $\sum_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m}{j}\beta^{j}(1-\alpha)^{j}(1-\beta)^{m-j} = (1-\alpha\beta)^{m}$
Context:
I want to split bezier curve of degree N at a certain $\alpha$. Then we have a new set of control points for the left and the right part (both forming again bezier curves). When want to evaluate the left bezier curve at $\beta$, i want to show, that this is the same as evaluating the original curve at $\alpha*\beta$.
Point on the left curve of the split.
$$
P_L = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}\beta^{i}(1-\beta)^{n-i}B_{Li}
$$
Control points of the left curve.
$$
B_{Li} = \sum_{j=0}^{i} \binom{i}{j}\alpha^{j}(1-\alpha)^{i-j}B_j
$$
After some magic and expansion and reduction, i come to this point.
$$
P_L = \sum_{i=0}^{n}B_i \binom{n}{i} \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} \binom{n-i}{j}\alpha^{i}\beta^{i+j}(1-\alpha)^{j}(1-\beta)^{n-i-j}
$$
I concentrate on this part
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-i} \binom{n-i}{j}\alpha^{i}\beta^{i+j}(1-\alpha)^{j}(1-\beta)^{n-i-j}
$$
which must be equal to
$$
(\alpha\beta)^{i}(1-\alpha\beta)^{n-i}
$$
reduce and reformulate a little bit and get this. And that's the point where I get stuck.
Problem
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m}{j}\beta^{j}(1-\alpha)^{j}(1-\beta)^{m-j} = (1-\alpha\beta)^{m}
$$
Do you have any hint or idea how to proceed from here? Any help is appreciated.

This is just Binomial expansion. Note that $(1-\alpha) \beta +(1-\beta)=1-\alpha\beta$. So $(1-\alpha\beta )^{n}= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \binom n j [(1-\alpha) \beta)]^{j} (1-\beta)^{n-j}$

Thank you very much, this was the hint i needed. :)
